# Deleting data on an unfamiliar database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a tedious situation and I was looking for a "less tedious" way to do it.

As it stands, I was asked to delete some data from the database -- no big deal, that's easy right? Wrong.

This database I have not worked on, so I am unfamiliar with the Primary/Foreign Key relationship, which is the tedious part because there are about 15-20 tables that are pretty intricately joined together.

What is the fastest way to delete indexed data without knowing the PK/FK relationship and having to go one by one with `DELETE FROM ... WHERE [something] = [somethingElse]` and finding out it's depending on another table's keys?

Comment: Is this database in a production environment?

Comment: @RickS yes. Backups have been made already.

Comment: The fastest way is to Drop the FKs.  The ways that work without logically invalidating the data are to 1) take the time to figure out the data and FK relations yourself, or 2) use the application to do it.  This is a case of FAST=WRONG.

Comment: @RBarryYoung absolutely correct. Especially on a production Database there is no excuse to use a fast, but wrong way. (Dropping the keys would take the same if not more time as learning the relationships anyways).

Comment: Fastest way is to try the delete, have a look at the error message and take appropriate action. Delete rows in the other table(s) or clear the FK if it is allowed. Rerun the entire transaction with the new stuff and repeat the steps untill there is no more errors.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson yeah that was the way I just did. Turns out subqueries make it a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can interrogate the sys.foreign_keys system view to get information on all FK relationships. It is not too much of a stretch from there to create DROP and CREATE statements.

I have a function that returns a variety of statements (e.g. DROP, CREATE, CHECK) for all the FKs for a partiuclar table. Running this function in Management Studio and returning the results to Text can give you nicely formatted statements to remove all FKs easily, delete your data, and then add the FKs back in afterwards.

Hopefully you can tailor it to your needs.

Hope it helps,

Ash

```
CREATE FUNCTION [utils].[uf_ForeignKeyScripts]
    (
@PrimaryKeyTable        varchar(128) 
,   @PrimaryKeyTableSchema  varchar(32)
)
RETURNS @Scripts TABLE 
    (
    ForeignKeyName          varchar(64)
,   IfExistsStatement       varchar(1000)
,   DropStatement           varchar(1000)
,   IfNotExistsStatement    varchar(1000)
,   CreateStatement         varchar(1000)
,   CheckStatement          varchar(1000)
,   NoCheckStatement        varchar(1000)
    )
    AS

/*
This function returns statements used to create, drop, and check all Foreign Key constraints that reference a given table.
These statements can be then added to T-SQL scripts.

Example usage (ensure selection of the Results to Text option in SSMS) :

1) To create statements to check all foreign keys

SELECT
    IfExistsStatement + CHAR(13) +
    CHAR(9) + CheckStatement + CHAR(13)
FROM
    utils.uf_ForeignKeyScripts('t_Dim_Date','dbo')      
    ;

This will return a formatted statement to check the existence of a foreign key and if it exists, check that data does not violate the key.

*/

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        @Scripts
        (
        ForeignKeyName
    ,   IfExistsStatement
    ,   DropStatement
    ,   IfNotExistsStatement
    ,   CreateStatement
    ,   CheckStatement
    ,   NoCheckStatement
        )
    SELECT
        FK.name AS ForeignKeyName
    ,   'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + FK.name + ''') ' + 
        'AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '''))'
        AS IfExistsStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' + 
        'DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + CHAR(13) + ';' 
        AS DropStatement
    ,   'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + FK.name + ''') ' + 
        'AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '''))'
        AS IfNotExistsStatement 
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + ' ' + 
        'FOREIGN KEY (' + C.FKColumns + ') ' + 
        'REFERENCES ' + ST.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) + ' ' + 
        '(' + C.FKColumns + ')' + CHAR(13) + ';' 
        AS CreateStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name + CHAR(13) + ';'
        AS CheckStatement
    ,   'ALTER TABLE ' + SFK.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ' ' +
        'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name +   CHAR(13) + ';'
        AS NoCheckStatement
    FROM
        sys.foreign_keys AS FK
    INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS SFK -- schema of foreign key table
    ON
        FK.schema_id = SFK.schema_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.tables AS T -- primary key table
    ON
        FK.referenced_object_id = T.object_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas AS ST -- schema of primary key table
    ON
        T.schema_id = ST.schema_id
    CROSS APPLY
        (
        /* Get all columns to handle composite keys */
        SELECT 
            SFKC.constraint_object_id
        ,   utils.uf_ConcatanateStringWithDelimiter(COL_NAME(SFKC.referenced_object_id, SFKC.referenced_column_id),', ') AS FKColumns
        FROM
            sys.foreign_key_columns AS SFKC
        WHERE
            SFKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
        GROUP BY
            SFKC.constraint_object_id
        )
        AS C
    WHERE
        OBJECT_NAME(T.object_id) = @PrimaryKeyTable
    AND ST.name = @PrimaryKeyTableSchema
    ;
    RETURN 
END
```